Xubuntu 23.10: add hibernate to XFCE
Technically hibernate works. I can use it by systemctl hibernate. But I need to add hibernate button to XFCE and add hibernate on low charge to XFCE power manager.
I tried to add to /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
##NEW entry since Ubuntu 18:
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

##NEW entry since Ubuntu 18:
[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

but it didn't help.
